# Number of read and write operation done by process on linux

Tags: ubuntu

How to get number of **write and read operations performed** by process(PID) in linux?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Comment: What is your use case? There are different approaches for different purposes, some do and others do  not require setting up before the process starts, other approaches can also start such accounting for processes that are already running, some are real time, others not so much while others others are more of debug tool. `iotop` for example is a simple console/command-line tool that shows realtime IO stats with options to narrow down to UID or PID.

Answer (score 0):

- Manual: `cat /proc/PIDNUMBER/io`
  Or for multiple: `for pidnumber in somepid otherpid pidthree ; do cat /proc/$pidnumber/io ; done`

If you want to sort it will all depend on how you want to sort and how you want the output to look. You can do this by piping to commands like `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `sort` or my favorite: doing everything at once by piping to `perl`

- With a UI: Multiple options are available with `iotop` as most famous one